# Keep percentage of rows of dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have a dataframe like that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A','A', 'A', 'B','B'], 'value':[2, 4, 6, 3, 4]})
```

I want to filter this only for `id`=`A` and keep an x percentage of the rows having `id`=`A`.

For example if x=60% then the dataframe should look like that:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     2
1    A     4
2    B     3
2    B     4
```

How can I do this efficiently in `pandas`?

Just to clarify that it is not necessary that all the `id`=A rows are the one after each other.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `iloc[]` with `pd.concat`

```
x = 0.6
cond = df['id'].eq('A')
out = pd.concat((df[cond].iloc[:int(round(df['id'].eq('A').sum() * x))],
                 df[~cond]),sort=False).sort_index()
```

---

```
  id  value
0  A      2
1  A      4
3  B      3
4  B      4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [df.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to achieve that easily

```
ids = ['A']
frac = 0.6
df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=frac) 
                                                   if x.name in ids else x)
```

Out:

```
    id  value
1   A   4
0   A   2
3   B   3
4   B   4
```